# Callback when scene is woken?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I want to run some code when the scene is woken, is there something i could use, possibly like this?

```
class MyScene extends Phaser.Scene{
     constructor(){
          super('scene')
     }
     preload(){
          //load some stuff
     }
     create(){
          //add some stuff
          
          this.scene.onUpdate = ()=>{
               //do some more stuff
        }
     }
     update(){
          //do some stuff
   }
}
```

PS: Putting the code in the update function won't work for me.

Comment: What does "scene is woken" mean?

Comment: @ScottMarcus https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/scenes/sleep-and-wake

Comment: Pointing me to a site with a code dump on it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Scene.sleep and scene.wake are methods for pausing and resuming scenes without shuttung them down and therefore wiping any changes made by the player for the next time they go back,

Comment: Ok, but "woken" is not a word and so I was confused. Do you mean "awaken"?

Comment: @ScottMarcus yes, it is a word, you can look it up if you so please.

Comment: @MrToenails the tutorial you posted doesn't work for you? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @winner_joiner I need a way for a scene to detect and run a callback when it is woken up, that example is just how to use wake/sleep

Comment: Wouldn't it be awake at the end of the wake event?

Comment: @ScottMarcus yes, but it just picks up where it left off, so I need a specific way of detecting when it wakes up that's not just constantly doing or checking if it needs to be done in the update loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be I'm misunderstanding something, but you can use the `Phaser.Scenes.Events.WAKE` as in the example, to do stuff when the Scene wakes up, by means of `switch` or `wake`.

If this demo doesn't clear things up, can we use it as baseline to explain the desired functionality *(You could copy it into your question, explaining, where and when code should be called)*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
   
    scene: [
      {key:'Scene1', create: create1},
      {key:'Scene2', create: create2}
     ],
    banner: false
}; 


function create1(){
  this.add.text(10,10, 'SCENE 1\n\n WakeLog:')
  
  let button = this.add.text(config.width/2, config.height/2, 'clickme').setOrigin(.5).setInteractive();
  
  let wakeLog = '';
  
  wakeLogLabel = this.add.text(10, 60, '');
  
  button.on('pointerdown', () =>{
    this.scene.switch('Scene2')
  });
  
  this.events.on(Phaser.Scenes.Events.WAKE, function() {
      // here you can call call the callback
      wakeLog += '  I was awaken\n'
      wakeLogLabel.setText(wakeLog);
  });
}

function create2() {
    this.add.text(10,10, 'SCENE 2')

    let button = this.add.text(config.width/2, config.height/2, 'click me to go to Scene1').setOrigin(.5).setInteractive();
    button.on('pointerdown', () =>{
      this.scene.switch('Scene1')
    });
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```